# Avoiding mixed content messages when using a custom URL Protocol from secure webpages

Tags: ssl, https, mixed-content, custom-protocol

I'm researching how to use Custom URL Application Protocols (such as custom://) to launch my local installed application.
When I'm accessing my website on http (without SSL) everyting runs fine and when enetering the page the local application get's started.

Switching to https the website shows the "secured" sign but when navigating to the page the local application is started but the "secured" sign is gone
When debugging the page it shows the message: 
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://....' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'custom://myapp/jivknjco'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.” Is appearing.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?